# Unix: Korn Shell if condition

Tags: shell-script, ksh

Im running a command to get information about FC cards names and saving to variable. Some servers those cards might not be available. on those machines the Variable saves a whitespace character. I want to use the If condition to check if the variable has whitespaces and then act accordingly.

The below one doesnt seems to work .

```
if [ "$VAR" == null ]
then
print "No special card Found"
else
#Run  a command
fi
```

Comment: What makes you believe a space character and the string "null" are the same string?

Comment: In what way did it "not work"? Could you please help us with your input?

Answer (score 1):

To specifically test for a single space character, use

```
if [ "$VAR" = ' ' ]; then
    print 'No special card found'
else
    # do something else
fi
```

If you want to check whether the variable is *empty*, then use

```
if [ -z "$VAR" ]; then
   # etc.
```

Comment: Hello Kusalananda, It didnt work

Comment: @satsensort Ah, I see. What makes you think that your "it did not work" will help us understand what happened? It is the most useless type of bug report you can ever give a developer, and the only thing it does is that it shows a lack of interest in actually wanting to solve the problem at all. We can't read your mind or see what's going on on your screen. Could you please help us solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

The first line stands for *if the variable `$VAR` is empty*

```
if [[ ! $VAR ]]; then
    print "No special card Found"
else
    #Run  a command
fi
```

or *explicitly* with `-z` switch

```
if [[ -z $VAR ]]; then
    print "No special card Found"
else
    #Run  a command
fi
```

Comment: Hello Giles, It didnt work.

Comment: Have you tested since @ikkachu edited to correct my typo ?